# Database Error (Matrix 2.4.3)

Tags: matrix

Get the following error when clicking on Add-Ons/Fieldtypes/Matrix. Can anyone help? Thanks.

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1060

Duplicate column name 'var_id'

ALTER TABLE exp_matrix_cols ADD var_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AFTER field_id, ADD INDEX (var_id)

Filename: third_party/matrix/ft.matrix.php

Line Number: 467

**Update**

Updated EE to 2.6.1 and updated all Add-ons I have installed (left Matrix for last). Tried updating Matrix to 2.5.5 and now get the following error when trying to edit any entry:

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'is_draft' in 'where clause'

SELECT row_id, col_id_21, col_id_22, col_id_28 FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE field_id = 55 AND entry_id = 75 AND is_draft = 0 ORDER BY row_order ASC

Filename: third_party/matrix/ft.matrix.php

Line Number: 2912

**Note**

Matrix 2.4.3 is working except that I can't add license key or update.

Comment: Hey Neils, if you've visited the field settings and you're still running into this, please email support@pixelandtonic.com with Super Admin and PHPMyAdmin details and we can get this fixed up for you. Thank you!

Comment: Lisa, I'm running into the same issue. Do you have the query I can run myself?

Comment: I ran into the same issue.  When I visit Addons > Fieldtypes > Matrix, I got several php errors, but when I refresh it appears the script ran.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the response I got from P&T support regarding this error. Solved the issue for me:

```
Take a look at the columns in exp_matrix_data table in the database.

* Does it have a field var_id? If no, then the version you should set is 2.2.
* If yes, does it have a field is_draft? If no, then the version you should set is 2.3
* If yes, then the version you should set is 2.5.10

Now, set the version number we determined in the previous three steps for the Matrix field in the exp_fieldtypes table and go visit the Add-ons -> Fieldtypes -> Matrix page and hit submit.

Everything should be all working now.
```

Comment: Thank you @Bjørn Børresen Having to move an old site before update and this helped me figure out someone had updated the files but not the db, so i could revert it and get site working

Comment: No problem @tristanbailey - glad you got it working :-)

Answer (score 3):

Upload all the files of Matrix 2.5.5. Then go to Add-Ons > Fieldtypes > Matrix to trigger [its update script](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/installation.html).

Comment: I tried that and that's when I began getting the other error when editing entries.

Comment: Instead of an update script I only get PHP errors.